# How to solve certain topology issues

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]I have a huge issue with topology that is really holding me back. When edges are close to eachother you get shading issues with subsurface divisions. I dont know if it is the way i model or something else, but i allways get this issue while modeling. No tutorial that i have found deals with this.

You can see there appears to be an edge on my meshes surface. Whats causing this is that there is a slight curve on the mesh (it doesnt appear on meshes that is symmetrical like a cube), and three edgeloops close together. The edgeloops creates a sharp curve on the top, whcih i want. I know i can slide the verticies away at the bottom, but when i say this is an issue i have often it is clear that i dont allways have that option.

If you have a sugestion on how to fix it, or you can direct me to a video, blog or some other learning resource i would appriciate it.

[image] [image]

Comment: Is this by any chance a ship hull?

Comment: No, it is a gun part.

Answer (score 3):

If your side is round, then you can use this topology, the tris won't create any pinching or artifacts here:

[image]

[image]

View from top:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115054/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-how-to-solve-certain-topology-issues).